# Dynamically change preload script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is there a way to set/change the `preload` option in `webPreferences` after `BrowserWindow` has been created?

What I would like to do is make a webcrawler that changes its `preload` script whenever the BrowserWindow redirects to a new URL.

The issue that I am trying to solve is that the webcrawler needs to collect different information on different sites.

The only 2 solutions I can think of are:

1. make 1 massive preload script that covers every website or
2. create a new `BrowserWindow` with a different preload script each time it redirects,

but neither seems resource efficient.

Is it possible to change or use different preload scripts without using multiple instances of the `BrowserWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

no, preload script is tied to per-process browserwindow creation, not per-url navigation inside of browserwindow.